# Give Space in SQL String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL string stored in table column, and it contains character like this 
`201603030040000`

So i want to have a result like this

`2016 0303 0004 0000`

I already tried with stuff,

`SET @output = (SELECT Stuff(Voucherid, 5, 0, ' ') + ';' FROM #tmpBus FOR XML PATH(''))`

But unfortunately it give me an result like this

`2016 030300040000`

is there a workaround for this issue ?

Comment: Do you always want it in the xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your data is always 12 characters and you always want a 4, 4, 4, 4 split then you can use `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT LEFT(columna, 4) + ' ' + 
       SUBSTRING(columna, 5, 4)+ ' ' + 
       SUBSTRING(columna, 7, 4)+ ' ' + 
       SUBSTRING(columna, 9, 4)+ ' ' + 
       SUBSTRING(columna, 11, 4)
FROM yourtable
```

Outputs:

```
2016 0303 0300 0040 4000
```

Comment: ah nice idea use substring on select query. yup for this case the value will always the same, and split each 4 character

Comment: @Sabilv The simplest solutions are sometimes the best. You could write a function for this and call it if its used a lot in different places also.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT have,
  SUBSTR(have,1,4)
  ||' '
  ||SUBSTR(have,5,4)
  ||' '
  || SUBSTR(have,9,4)
  ||' '
  || SUBSTR(have,12) AS want
FROM
  ( SELECT '201603030040000' AS have FROM dual
  );
```

Comment: This is SQL Server; this syntax is therefore wrong in at least two ways.